How to get Bazel to build an external third party library with a python build script
So, I'm attempting to build OpenUSD in my Bazel project. Its a giant repo, but they provide a nice build.py Python program which handles all of their dependencies and making their CMake project.
I've gotten it build using genrule's by having it output to a zip file, but the issue is the genrule requires all outputs be specified. This gives me a full giant tree of includes, lib, bin, etc containing about 75,000 files. How do I go about getting this to be usable in a cc_library rule?
genrule(
    name = "openusd_genrule",
    srcs = [
        "@openusd//:all_srcs",
    ],
    outs = [ 
        "usd.zip"
     ],
    tags = [
        "requires-network",
    ],
    local = True,
    cmd = "&&".join([
        "$(execpath @openusd//:build_usd) temp_usd",
        "zip -r $@ temp_usd"
    ]),
    tools = [
        "@openusd//:build_usd",
    ],
)

